# 20.04 unresponsive windows, unresponsive desktop, high RAM usage

Tags: gnome-shell

When I restart `gnome-shell` using `alt + F2 + r` major issues like:

1. Unresponsive windows
2. Unresponsive desktop
3. High RAM usage

get fixed perfectly. So, why exactly does it work and what exactly happens when you restart `gnome-shell`?

When I run `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` I see

```
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 abhay abhay 4096 May 16 15:08 .
drwx------ 3 abhay abhay 4096 Jun  1 03:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 abhay abhay 4096 May 16 15:02 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 abhay abhay 4096 May  3 15:28 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

When I run `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` I see

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May 23 01:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:05 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:05 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 27 15:38 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

When I run `free -h` I see

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       1.5Gi       4.9Gi       289Mi       1.1Gi       5.5Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

When I run `top` I see

```
top - 23:26:52 up 6 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.01, 1.02, 0.57
Tasks: 300 total,   1 running, 299 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7801.6 total,   5044.1 free,   1599.8 used,   1157.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used.   5666.4 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                          
   1757 abhay     20   0  912636 118792  79564 S   3.3   1.5   0:35.37 Xorg                                                                             
   2382 abhay     20   0  965964  49564  37136 S   3.3   0.6   0:05.89 gnome-terminal-                                                                  
   2002 abhay     20   0 4924592 277768 116092 S   2.3   3.5   0:36.19 gnome-shell                                                                      
   2608 abhay     20   0 2895956 378652 191188 S   0.7   4.7   0:35.07 Web Content                                                                      
      1 root      20   0  167704  11632   8480 S   0.3   0.1   0:03.13 systemd                                                                          
   1956 abhay     20   0  162812   7596   6816 S   0.3   0.1   0:00.20 at-spi2-registr                                                                  
   2496 abhay     20   0 3564084 393188 186492 S   0.3   4.9   1:03.71 firefox                                                                          
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                         
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                           
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                       
      5 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0-cgroup_destroy                                                       
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                             
      7 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 kworker/0:1-events                                                               
      8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.98 kworker/u24:0-events_unbound                                                     
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                     
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0                                                                      
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.41 rcu_sched                                                                        
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                      
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                    
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                          
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                          
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                    
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 migration/1                                                                      
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1                                                                      
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                             
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                                          
     22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                                    
     23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 migration/2                                                                      
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2                                                                      
     26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd                                                             
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                                          
     28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                                    
     29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.07 migration/3                                                                      
     30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3
```

When I run `systemd-analyze blame` I see

```
1min 30.122s nmbd.service                                         
     12.973s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     11.924s udisks2.service                                      
     11.297s snapd.service                                        
      8.876s samba-ad-dc.service                                  
      7.313s dev-sdb3.device                                      
      5.269s NetworkManager.service                               
      5.225s accounts-daemon.service                              
      4.762s polkit.service                                       
      3.740s ModemManager.service                                 
      3.666s avahi-daemon.service                                 
      3.665s bluetooth.service                                    
      3.300s switcheroo-control.service                           
      3.295s thermald.service                                     
      3.292s wpa_supplicant.service                               
      3.291s systemd-logind.service                               
      2.996s dev-loop4.device                                     
      2.970s gpu-manager.service                                  
      2.881s dev-loop5.device                                     
      2.798s systemd-resolved.service                             
      2.622s dev-loop3.device                                     
      2.496s apport.service                                       
      2.443s grub-common.service                                  
      2.006s gdm.service                                          
      1.915s dev-loop0.device                                     
      1.761s rsyslog.service                                      
      1.756s secureboot-db.service                                
      1.640s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
      1.373s dev-loop2.device                                     
      1.370s dev-loop1.device                                     
       995ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
       823ms upower.service                                       
       816ms pppd-dns.service                                     
       776ms e2scrub_reap.service                                 
       738ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E866\x2d1E0F.service
       723ms systemd-modules-load.service                         
       717ms apparmor.service                                     
       713ms tlp.service                                          
       542ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
       541ms systemd-random-seed.service                          
       515ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
       508ms snapd.seeded.service                                 
       507ms smbd.service                                         
       480ms systemd-journald.service                             
       457ms swapfile.swap                                        
       434ms systemd-udevd.service                                
       430ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
       347ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
       342ms keyboard-setup.service                               
       333ms snap-bitwarden-25.mount                              
       319ms colord.service                                       
       318ms snap-bitwarden-24.mount                              
       299ms snap-core18-1754.mount                               
       266ms snap-snapd-7264.mount                                
       256ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
       255ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount              
       240ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
       235ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount              
       227ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
       224ms kerneloops.service                                   
       213ms binfmt-support.service                               
       196ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
       182ms setvtrgb.service                                     
       175ms ufw.service                                          
       141ms openvpn.service                                      
       140ms geoclue.service                                      
       135ms user@1000.service                                    
       127ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
       106ms console-setup.service                                
       104ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
        98ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
        97ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
        96ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
        96ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
        92ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
        89ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
        85ms boot-efi.mount                                       
        67ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
        28ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
        25ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
        25ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                        
        23ms systemd-journal-flush.service                        
        14ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
        13ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
         9ms alsa-restore.service                                 
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
         3ms plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
         3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
       825us snapd.socket
```

When I run `cat /etc/fstab` I see

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=729e17ba-8e24-41fb-ab2d-779ba62bfb60 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=E866-1E0F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

When I run `cat /etc/samba/smb.conf` I see

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
   logging = file

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
#   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

When I run `testparm` I see

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

`Swappiness` is set to `60`.

Comment: Probably a bad GNOME Shell extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `top`.

Comment: Restarting Windows fixes everything too.

Comment: Thank you for the info. After updating your question with requested info, make sure to send a comment that starts with @heynnema so that I'll get notified. I almost missed your update. Anyway, the `top` command is incomplete, and doesn't show what processes are consuming CPU time. Can you please redo that command for me?

Comment: I would rather ask why you get unresponsive windows and desktop. I don't have that ...

Comment: @pLumo I don't understand your point. OP did ask about those things.

Comment: OP asks "why exactly does it work and what exactly happens when you restart `gnome-shell`?"

Comment: @heynnema I have done the changes. Hope this will help.

Comment: It looks like you've deleted some GNOME Shell extensions, and everything looks ok now. Your first `top` command showed 5 running processes that were taking over 100% of your CPU, but I don't see those now. Is there anything specific in the current outputs that concerns you?

Comment: @heynnema I have posted the results of systemd-analyze blame. It is concerning that one service alone takes 1 min 30 secs to start. But my whole computer reaches to desktop in 80 seconds. Is that a problem?

Comment: Are you mounting some Samba network shares at boot time? Show me `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema I dont use samba, but recently I tried to experiment with it. I installed, and then to uninstall i used purge and also I searched for all files named as samba and deleted them. Then I realised that some samba files were present even before when I didnt install samba. So I recovered those files from a live boot by copy pasting them. I dont need samba anyhow currently.

Comment: Samba sounds like it's messed up. If you installed files by getting them from a Ubuntu Live DVD, then you probably caused it. Show me `cat /etc/samba/smb.conf`. Boot time to desktop should be much less than 80 secs, depending on the processor, and version of Ubuntu. What version Ubuntu? Better yet, show me `testparm`.

Comment: When you were playing with Samba, did you share out any folders?

Comment: @heynnema I have provided the outputs of both of them. I use intel i7-8750H (pretty powerful), with Ubuntu 20.04 lts (HDD) in triple boot alongside with windows 10(SSD)and Pop! OS (HDD).

Comment: @heynnema Yes I tried it but Didnt work. So I decided to remove it. Just tell me how to completely remove samba.

Comment: I re-titled your question so that it wouldn't get closed. If you remember which folders you tried to share out, see if you can un-share them. You don't really want to remove Samba, but you may wish to properly reinstall it. Run the system for a while and see if your original problem is fixed. ps: your system should get to Desktop in less than 20 seconds.

Comment: @heynnema I reinstalled all the samba packages installed on my pc with sudo apt install samba samba-vfs-modules samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs samba-dsdb-modules --reinstall. This seems to have done the work. And about the boot time, there is no way it will take 20 seconds. Earlier I had 18.04lts even that took 50 seconds, and even 20.04 lts out of the box took 50 seconds. If I should have 20seconds, pls tell me where can I cut some time. Also if I dont use samba, then can I uninstall it. Or are there any system dependencies on samba

Comment: Look at `systemd-analyze blame` again. With my lowly i5, I can get to the Desktop in less than 20 seconds (with SSD), so you should be able to also (unless you've got a slow HDD).

Comment: @heynnema for my pc boot time and ```systemd-analyze time``` are very different. I get 32 now (earlier it was 23) with ```systemd-analyze time```.

Comment: Your system looks fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

- removed a bunch of GNOME Shell extensions to solve high usage.
- reinstalled Samba to cure `nmbd` problem

  ```
  sudo apt install samba samba-vfs-modules samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs samba-dsdb-modules --reinstall
  ```
- system boot times ~30 seconds
- GNOME Shell CPU/memory usage is now normal

Comment: `removed a bunch of GNOME Shell extensions to solve high usage.` How to find them ?

Comment: @fuat Please start a new question, and give more details about your problem. Thanks!